# Printing initialized structure

Tags: c, sockets

Following code is printing protoent structure.

Unless I do `getprotoent()` I can’t print structure variable although I initialize it.

It ends segmentation falter if I don’t `getprotoent().`

Does anyone know this?

Samle.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int
main(){
        struct protoent *proto;
        memset(&proto,0,sizeof(proto));
        proto = getprotoent();

        printf("proto.p_name = %s\n",(*proto).p_name);
        printf("proto.p_aliases = %s\n",*(*proto).p_aliases);
        printf("proto.p_proto = %d\n",(*proto).p_proto);
}
```

Comment: cause without getprotoent, you have not assign any memory to the structure pointer.

Comment: The `memset` is simply `proto = NULL`, so it's a waste of time.

Comment: `*proto` is just a pointer, you never "initialize" it, of course you get segment fault trying to dereference it. You need to malloc memory for it, what is most likely being done in getprotoent().

Comment: Where is `getprotoent()`?

Comment: Also please use `x->` instead of `(*x).`

Comment: @Purrfection : Just for my knowledge, why `x->` is better than `(*x).`? What I know is both are same and can be used alternately, though the first way is more readable.

Comment: @0xF1 You just answered your own question :) Shorter to type and more readable.

Comment: Thanks @Purrfection I thought it is some kind of UB or some compatibility issue (which of course, I am not aware of). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

`struct protoent proto;`
`memset(&proto,0,sizeof(proto));`

As `*proto` is a pointer to structure, it can just hold the address of a variable of `struct protoent` type. Your statement doesn't actually initializes the structure.

More Explanation:

`struct protoent *proto;`
`memset(&proto,0,sizeof(proto));`

On some system, this may be same as `struct protoent *proto = NULL;`

Since you are actually "**assigning 0 to the pointer**"

After that you are dereferencing it in `printf` statement, that will surely cause seg fault.

**EDIT/UPDATE**: Suggested by [user694733](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694733/user694733) in the comments

Not all system assign address `0` to the NULL pointer. It is a translation to some address reserved as `NULL` which is done by compiler when you do `<datatype> *ptr = 0;`. However doing `memset(&ptr,0,sizeof(ptr));` will not be understood by compiler as `NULL assignment` on these systems and it will simply assign address `0` to `ptr` which as I said may not be a `NULL`.

For more understanding, Please read [this link](http://c-faq.com/null/machnon0.html) or the complete [C-FAQ chapter](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html) about `NULL` pointers.

I would also like to cite [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20718572/2628863) on SO.

Comment: `memset` does *not* equal `proto = NULL;` on all systems.

Comment: @user694733 : Please can you explain that with some example? because I believe that if `NULL` is `#defined` as `0`, then that will always be true.

Comment: True, but compiler does conversion to real value if necessary for the system. `memset` on the other hand happens at runtime. See [the C FAQ question 5.5](http://c-faq.com/null/machnon0.html). The whole chapter 5 of the faq explains NULL pointers in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `memset` is the same as if you would do

```
proto = 0; // Which is not neccessarily the same as NULL.
```

It doesn't allocate memory, it just initializes the pointer.

If you want to derference the pointer, you have to assign it some valid memory, which apparently `getprotoent()` is allocating. Dereferencing the NULL pointer would cause the program to abort which is correct.

Comment: @Koushik, it's not undefined, because it doesn't dereference the pointer. It is useless though and confusing.

Comment: `memset` does *not* equal `proto = NULL;` on all systems.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
//this defines pointer variable
struct protoent *proto;  

//this does not allocate memory for the pointer variable
memset(&proto,0,sizeof(proto));
```

So whenever you dereference it without allocating it or calling `getprotoent`, it will fail.